# Issues with passing fstream as an input using getline

Tags: c++, graph, fstream, getline

Please excuse me if this has been posted before. I tried searching for this but couldn't describe my problem.

I am working on a project right now that has us finding connections in a graph. The program can either accept user input from the terminal or from an input file. I have created a driver function that takes an istream as a parameter which is dependent on whether or not the user is inputting commands from the terminal or passing them in from an input file.

I think my problem is coming from "getline". I use getline because some of the vertices have names with a space in them. The program works when I use cin, but has problems with fstream.

The program executes different searches depending on the user's input. If I use getline with cin, the program can understand the commands but it does not work with getline and fstream. If I pass the fstream to a string using the >> operator, there's no issue, but the getline commands that read the search queries come up as blanks after that. I've also tried cin.ignore() to no avail.

Here's the function in question:

```
void six_degrees::start(string filename, istream &input, ostream &output_type)
{
    populate(filename);
    string command;
    string source;
    string dest;

    while (input)
    {
        input >> command; // used to be a getline() but had issues reading when passing fstream

        if (command == "dfs")
        {
            input.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // didn't work
            getline(input, source);
            getline(input, dest);
            if (database_check(source) && database_check(dest))
            {
                print_path(output_type, degrees.dfs(source, dest), source, dest);
            }
        }
        else if (command == "bfs")
        {
            getline(input, source);
            getline(input, dest);
            if (database_check(source) && database_check(dest))
            {
                print_path(output_type, degrees.report_path(source, dest), source, dest);
            }
        }
        else if (command == "not")
        {

            getline(input, source);
            getline(input, dest);
            string list;
            vector<Artist> exclude;

            while (list != "*")
            {
                getline(input, list);
                exclude.push_back(list); // uses getter to return artist instance
            }
            if (database_check(source) && database_check(dest))
            {
                if (exclusion_check(exclude))
                {
                    print_path(output_type, degrees.not_search(source, dest, exclude), source, dest);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (command == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << command << " is not a command. Please try again" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There should be no difference whether you're pulling from an `fstream` vs pulling from the console (so long as the source file was *not* opened in binary mode (looking at you, Windows).  Your post should include a populated source file for an example that triggers the problem you claim you're facing. I can see a number of places in this code where you're potentially one-off on your read vs validation locations, and I strongly suspect that is contributing to the problems you're facing, but attributing to `getline` erroneously.

Comment: you are going to have to supply, a) code that we can read and test b) an input file that exhibits the error you describe

Comment: Interesting you mention windows. I'm using PowerShell to compile (usually use bash) I'll see if that does anything different and come back with the full code if it does not

Answer (score 0):

@WhozCraig figured it out. I was using windows powershell which caused the issue. I logged into my schools remote server that uses linux (where they're supposed to be anyway) and didn't have a problem.